# SonarQube web api: retrieving number of "won't fix" issues on TimeMachine API

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-web

I would like to retrieve the number of "false positives" and "won't fix" a project has along the time, so I am using the TimeMachine API.

I am able to list the "false positives", but not the "won't fix", using below URL:

```
api/timemachine/index?metrics=false_positive_issues
```

But I did not see a metric for "Won't fix" on the [Metric Definitions](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Metric+definitions#MetricDefinitions-Issues) documentation.

There is a REST service, GET api/issue_filters/search, that allows retrieving info for both "false positives" and "won't fix", but only for current user.

I have two questions:

1. is there any way to get "Won't fix" numbers on the SonarQube web api?
2. if not, what would be the best way to get these numbers **per project**?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The metric to be used is "wont_fix_issues".

Example:

```
http://localhost:9000/api/timemachine/index?resource=1&metrics=wont_fix_issues
```

Thanks a lot to **G. Ann - SonarSource Team** for providing this answer through their support group!